# Using powershell with .NET returning null

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am using .NET with powershell trying to retrieve result of `Get-Acl` command of specific AD object. Unfortunately when I run the code from C# code I get 0 result. Also the `ThrowIfError` is not throwing any error.

```
Command test01 = new Command("import-module");
test01.Parameters.Add("name", "activedirectory");
session.Commands.AddCommand(test01);

Command test0 = new Command("Set-Location");
test0.Parameters.Add("Path", "AD:");
session.Commands.AddCommand(test0);

Command test1 = new Command("Get-Acl");
test1.Parameters.Add("Path", identity);
session.Commands.AddCommand(test1);

session.AddCommand("select-object");
session.AddParameter("Property", "Access");

var tempResults1 = session.Invoke();
ThrowIfError();

private void ThrowIfError()
{
    var errors = session.Streams.Error;
    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        var ex = errors[0].Exception;

        session.Streams.ClearStreams();

        // Never close session to dispose already running scripts.

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This code running on server in powershell is working correctly:

```
PS AD:\> Import-Module -Name activedirectory
PS AD:\> set-location ad:
PS AD:\> get-acl -path <distinguishedNameOfADObject>
```

**Question**

How to get the same result like I get from Powershell? I should get atleast something not a zero result.

**Little background:**

I am trying to get `Send-As` rights not using `Get-ADPermission` cmdlet because its taking too long time when I need to search for rights within thousands of mailboxes. Using this article [link](https://vanhybrid.com/2016/08/04/speeding-up-retrieval-of-send-as-permissions/) I am trying another approach to get the rights. I have already the slower version working using C# code:

```
Command command = new Command("Get-ADPermission");
            command.Parameters.Add("Identity", identity);
            session.Commands.AddCommand(command);

            session.AddCommand("where-object");
            ScriptBlock filter = ScriptBlock.Create("$_.ExtendedRights -eq 'send-as'");
            session.AddParameter("FilterScript", filter);

            session.AddCommand("select-object");
            session.AddParameter("Property", "User");

            tempResults = session.Invoke();
```

Comment: Why not use Directory.GetAccessControl directly ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to define a powershell-script instead of multiple commands to get the values you need. Example with your powershell-code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace GetAclPowershellTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            /****Create Powershell-Environment****/
            PowerShell PSI = PowerShell.Create(); 

            /****Insert PowershellScript****/
            string Content = "param($object); Import-Module ActiveDirectory; Set-Location AD:; Get-ACL -Path $object"; //Add Scrip
            PSI.AddScript(Content);
            PSI.AddParameter("object", "<distinguishedNameOfADObject>");

            /****Run your Script with PSI.Invoke()***/
            Collection<PSObject> PSIResults = PSI.Invoke();

            /****All Errors****/
            Collection<ErrorRecord> Errors = PSI.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

            /****needed, because garbagecollector ignores PSI otherwise****/
            PSI.Dispose(); 

            /**** Your ACL-Object ****/
            ActiveDirectorySecurity MyACL = (ActiveDirectorySecurity)PSIResults[0].BaseObject;

            /*insert your code here*/

        }
    }
}
```

This example works for me.

You have to set a reference to the Powershell-Assembly (Usually you can find it at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll")

Benefit of this solution is, you could read a .ps1-File you got from someone, fill the parameters with the objects you have and the script runs like in a standard powershell-session. The only requirement to set parameters is the param-part in the Script.

More Infos about param: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx

Hope, this helps...

Greetings, Ronny

Update:

```
string Content = "param($object); Import-Module ActiveDirectory; Set-Location AD:; (Get-ACL -Path $object).Access | Where-Object{($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq 'ExtendedRight') -and ($_.objectType -eq 'ab721a54-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b')}";
```

And the loop at the end looks like this now:

```
foreach (PSObject o in PSIResults)
            {
                ActiveDirectoryAccessRule AccessRule = (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule)o.BaseObject;

                /**do something with the AccessRule here**/
            }
```

Comment: I got a result using your solution but I am not familiar with `Select-Object` and `Where-Object` using pipelines. Since its a script I have modified your code like this: `string Content = "param($object); Import-Module ActiveDirectory; Set-Location AD:; Get-ACL -Path $object | select access | ?{($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq 'ExtendedRight') -and ($_.objectType -eq 'ab721a54-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b')}"; //Add Scrip` but this is not working. The test object was given a send-as rights so I should get atleast one result.

Comment: Use this as Script: "param($object); Import-Module ActiveDirectory; Set-Location AD:; (Get-ACL -Path $object).Access | Where-Object{($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq 'ExtendedRight') -and ($_.objectType -eq 'ab721a54-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b')}"

But beware: The result can now be a set of accessrules (If more than one has a send-as-right for the questioned object), you have to set the results in a  loop:

foreach (PSObject o in PSIResults)
{ ActiveDirectoryAccessRule AccessRule = (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule)o.BaseObject;
   /**do something here**/}

Comment: uh oh, unreadable, give me a moment, i put the changes in my answer

Comment: Select-Object can be used here, but is easier to pipe the Access-Collection to the Where-Object-Cmdlet (? is just an alias, i don't like aliases ;))

Comment: you deserve a medal! I was struggling with getting a name of user when you came with your additional comment! saved me a tons of time :)